# What is the difference between HttpContext.Current.Response and Page.Response?

Tags: asp.net, caching, http-headers, httpcontext

I'm troubleshooting a caching issue on a set of secured pages and have realized that the Header needs to be modified for all Responses.  As I put together a solution, I want to know the difference between HttpContext.Current.Response and Page.Response and when each object should be used in an app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Page.Response` is simply a mapping to the HTTPContext when you are within the context of an HTML page.

`HttpContext.Current.Response` simply allows you to get to the current context, when you are not in a page.  ALlowing you to access the context from locations other than the actual page responding to the request.

As for when to use each?  Well you "Can" use HttpContext.Current.Response everywhere if you want, but typically people will use Page.Response when on a page/usercontrol.

Comment: They are both references to the same instance of HttpResponse, too.

Comment: This doesn't appear so. Cookies set by one don't seem to be available to the other. Unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 5):

Well for starters Page.Response implies that you have a current, valid Page object, HttpContext is static and can be called at any time - like in your Global.asax or and HttpModule/HttpHandler.